# Как привести к типу Union из typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, union, typing

В ходе стажировки наткнулся на новый для себя тип Union, прочел документацию там пример
вот ссылка https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html
Понятный пример но не решает моей задачи.

У меня есть аргумент функции например

```
def myFunc(data: Dict[str, List[Tuple[str, str]]]):
```

а вернуть я должен вот такой тип `Dict[Union[str, int], Union[str, Tuple[str, str]]]`
Мне не нужно решение, скорее объяснение что за тип такой, можно на примере показать.
Спасибо.

Comment: С каких пор это офф документация? А как же https://docs.python.org/3/?

Comment: убрал слово офф из описания задачи, прошу прощения это не более чем опечатка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) обозначает, что значение может иметь один из типов перечисленных в квадратных скобках. Например `Union[str, int]` означает, что значение может иметь тип строки или целого числа.

`Dict[Union[str, int], Union[str, Tuple[str, str]]]` - словарь, в котором ключи целые числа или строки, а значения - строки или кортежи из двух строковых значений.

Comment: Спасибо больше разобрался

Answer (score 2):

`Union` просто говорит о том, что некое значение может иметь один из нескольких заданных типов. То есть, если указано, что функция возвращает `Union[str, int]`, то она может вернуть как строку, так и целое число.

Например:

```py
def multiply(value: Union[str, int], factor: int) -> Union[str, int]:
    return value * factor
```

Будет работать как со строками, так и с числами.

---

Официальную документацую пожалуйста не путайте, она расположена здесь: [docs.python.org: typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)

Comment: Да понял что слово офф было лишним ошибся

Answer (score 1):

Это словарь, ключами которого могут быть строки и числа, а значениями строки и кортежи из строк строк длинной 2 элемента.